# Cocos2d iOS: Why doesn't my CCMenuItemImage respond to touch events?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a new class to represent labels in the scene and I'm trying to figure out how to make them respond to touch events.  My code is very simple, but when I set a breakpoint in the selector specified in the initFromNormalImage method, the breakpoint never gets hit.  Here's my code...

interface file

```
@interface FBLabel : CCNode {
    CCMenuItemImage *_labelSprite;
    CCLabelBMFont *_info;
}
-(id) initWithLabelFileName: (NSString*) filename andInfo: (NSString*) inInfo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCMenuItemImage *labelSprite;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLabelBMFont *info;
@end
```

implementation file

```
@implementation FBLabel
@synthesize labelSprite = _labelSprite;
@synthesize info = _info;

-(id) initWithLabelFileName: (NSString*) filename andInfo: (NSString*) inInfo{

    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _labelSprite = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:filename selectedImage:filename target:self selector:@selector(checkSelectedItem:)];
        if(_labelSprite){
            [self addChild: _labelSprite z:1];
            self.contentSize = _labelSprite.contentSize;
        }
        //_info = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:inInfo fntFile:@"AppleLiGothic_Black18.fnt"];
        _info = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:inInfo fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:16.0];
        if(_info){
            _info.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0.5);
            _info.position = ccp(-80,0);
            [self addChild:_info z:2];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc{
    [_labelSprite release];
    [_info release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)checkSelectedItem:(id)sender {  
    //THIS LINE OF CODE NEVER GETS EXECUTED
    CCMenuItemImage *toggleItem = (CCMenuItemImage *)sender;

}
@end
```

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [CCMenu](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_menu.html) class as the parent for [CCMenuItem](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_menu_item.html) and derived classes. You are adding the CCMenuItemImage to self, which is a CCNode instance.

Instead, create a CCMenu class and add this to your node, and then add all CCMenuItem* instances to the CCMenu. Refer to [this tutorial for more details](http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle).